# can insert multiple instruction under one case excel-vba?

Tags: excel, vba

want to ask, can i use multiple instruction under one case statement?don't want to use if..then because i have more than 7 conditions. what i want to do is if the value of combobox is "this",then insert the new row at the correct row,then add the combobox value into the new created row. 
 here's the example:

```
Case ComboBox1.Value = "Venofix"
  instruction 1 ~> count the number of row of "venofix"
  instruction 2 ~> insert new row at the last row
  instruction 3 ~> insert data from combobox

Case ComboBox1.Value = "Penofix"
  instruction 1 ~> count the number of row of "penofix"
  instruction 2 ~> insert new row at the last row
  instruction 3 ~> insert data from combobox
```

Comment: Yes you can insert multiple instructions in one select case. You may want to see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278454.aspx For Global Variables see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx

Comment: @SiddharthRout try to look at the latest question.that's actually i'm asking. sorry if my question is kind of weird because i'm totally new to vba

Comment: Yes it will still work. I would however keep Instruction 2 and 3 out of the select case (not becuase it won't work inside the select case but simply because I would want to avoid duplicate code)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks.i'll avoid using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

Like I said in the comment `I would however keep Instruction 2 and 3 out of the select case (not because it won't work inside the select case but simply because I would want to avoid duplicate code)`

```
Sub Sample()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "Venofix"
        'instruction 1 ~> count the number of row of "venofix"
    Case "Penofix"
        'instruction 1 ~> count the number of row of "penofix"
    End Select

    'instruction 2 ~> insert new row at the last row
    'instruction 3 ~> insert data from combobox
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify multiple condition seprating by comma.

```
Sub Sample()

        Dim conDition As String
        conDition = ComboBox1.Value
        Select Case conDition
        Case "Venofix"
            Debug.Print "instruction 1"
        Case "Penofix"
          Debug.Print "instruction 1"
       Case "test1", "test2"
            Debug.Print "more than 1 instruction"
        End Select


    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks.but what i really mean is the instruction for each case,not the condition.